# Calculating the resistance of a resistor network

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, symmetry, electrical-resistance

I am trying to calculate the resistance of this resistor network between points A and B (simplified from a more complex one). I don't really know how to deal with the wire between the middle resistors, I was thinking about applying Kirkhoff laws, but I cannot imagine how would the current split in that part of the circuit.

[image: The resistor network]

Comment: Not sure homework-like questions are welcome, but you use Kirchoff's  current law to closed loops of your circuit. The rest is linear algebra (solving a system of equations)

Comment: *I don't really know how to deal with the wire between the middle resistors.* One way to think about it is as a zero-ohm resistor.

Comment: A "wire" in a circuit diagram is really just a graphical extension of a node. It has absolutely no meaning other than that it makes the circuit easier to draw. All 500 Ohm resistors are therefor connected to the same node.